# request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: asp.net, rest

Im exploring a system of applications i have not built and that doesnt have any documentation. Im trying to make an api request from it that fails. Iver tried two different ways one with Microsofts HttpClient and the other try is with the RestSharp librabry. Both work when i run them outside of  the application. From CH Fiddler onlie or a test application that i create just to debug.

What can there be in the application that stops the call and why?

The error i get:

> WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

**Method one:**

```
  var client = new HttpClient();
        var clientResponse = client.GetStringAsync("https://xkcd.com/info.0.json").Result;
        var clientJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(clientResponse);
        var imgUrl = clientJson.img;
```

**Method two**

```
    var restClient = new RestClient();
        restClient.BaseUrl = "https://xkcd.com";

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Resource = "/info.0.json";

        var response = restClient.Execute<dynamic>(request);

        // json["alt"] json["img"] eller json.img
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
        var x = json.img;
```

The application runs net 4.5.

Comment: It means (and you can google this error quite widely) that there's no valid SSL certificate installed for the domain where the API is hosted (or possibly that there is some certificate but the machine your client is running on doesn't trust it). Check whether the API really supports HTTPS or not, and whether the certificate is correct. Trying to access it through a browser might give you a visual indication

Comment: Thanks! Im trying to understand why this is an issue in this application and not in others.

Comment: By "others" do you mean other APIs, or other clients which call the same API? If the former, it depends if these "others" (whatever they are, and wherever they may be hosted) have a valid SSL certificate associated with them in the webserver config or not. If the latter, then maybe those programs make their HTTP request a different way. I can't see any of this, so I can only guess and speculate. It's very hard to spot differences in things you can't see. Have you got sight of any of these other applications? If so, then you can easily play spot the difference...

Comment: I meant how come this application cares about SSL and why others don’t. I guess there is a configuration.

Comment: what precsiely do you mean "cares about SSL"? All web applications which are served over HTTPS (instead of HTTP) have to "care about" SSL, and so do the clients which connect to them. I mean this in the sense that there has to be a valid SSL certificate provided by the webserver which is used to verify the encryption placed on the request, one which is trusted by both server and client. Do you know much about SSL / HTTPS in general?

Comment: No. Every time I create a new project from visual studio or run the code from C# Fiddler it works. Same request.

Comment: And when it doesn't work, are you executing the request in some different way, and/or from a different computer? Please be clear and specific. If so then the most likely issue is that the different computer or security context can't read or doesn't recognise the API's SSL certificate.

Comment: You can also look through the various previous articles on the subject in case that helps: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=WebException%3A+The+request+was+aborted%3A+Could+not+create+SSL%2FTLS+secure+channel.&oq=WebException%3A+The+request+was+aborted%3A+Could+not+create+SSL%2FTLS+secure+channel.&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.206j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Ok thanks. Everything has been done from the same computer, same code, same call, same url.

Comment: so what are the specific circumstances in which is does and does not work? It's not clear to me. You mention it works if you run it from Visual Studio, or from C# Fiddle. What are the exact circumstances where it _doesn't_ work?

Comment: It doesnt work in a specific asp.net application that i run from visual studio. 

It works if i create a new asp.net app in vs and run the code. 

It works if i run the code from C# fiddle.  Basically it works everywhere except this application i havent built. So im looking for clues to se what it is in the application that prevents it.

Comment: does this app run under a different identity perhaps? I'm still guessing here, there's nothing in your code above which gives any clue to it. I can't play spot the difference for you really. Maybe take a copy of this app, strip it down to the bare minimum removing everything not required to get to where this request happens, and see if you can weasel out the thing which causes the problem. And/or try and read about this subject and see if you can get any clues about what you need to look for more specifically. One more thing though, what .NET framework version is it running?

Answer (score 3):

you can also add this line before you do any request

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```